# Essentially, why do we even need package-lock.json and shrinkwrap?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json, shrinkwrap

Before anything, I'd like to mention I **do know** what `package.json`, `package-lock.json` and `npm shrinkwrap` technically do and how they differ. These are thoroughly documented all over the internet.

I would like to understand better why `package-lock.json` was created, and why `package.json` is not enough.

- If my `package.json` specifies exactly `foobar@1.2.3`, it will always install exactly `foobar@1.2.3`. **⇒ I do not need `package-lock.json`**.
- If my `package.json` specifies `foobar@~1.2.3`, then it means that I guarantee my lib works fine with any `foobar` lib equal or over `1.2.3`. Then I should not have to worry which version a user `npm install`s. **⇒ I do not need `package-lock.json`**.

It seems to me that `package-lock.json` was created for very pragmatic reasons, because every programmer carelessly writes `foobar@^1.2.3` in their `package.json` without testing every `1.x.x` version. Thus, adding `package-lock.json` is a way to say "I didn't test all the versions I claimed my lib works with, but at least I can guarantee it works with *this* specific version."

I understand `package.json`'s format is not very expressive. In particular, it does not have a way to express a **maximum** version with which the lib may not work in the absence of testing (e.g. when a new version of one of the deps is published).

Solution **A**: Always use fixed versions of packages in `package.json`.

Drawback of **A**: `npm` may not have much opportunity to mutualize dependencies among packages.

Solution **B**: Use version ranges in `package.json`, but make sure every single version from the claimed range work. In addition, an exclusion list could even be used.

Drawback of **B**: It could be tedious to test in a exhaustive way. It is also a combinatorial explosion if we want to test every version of a given dep with every single version of all others deps.

Is the existence of `package-lock.json` an acknowledgement that there are no good solution for this problem, and having at least one functional set of dep versions is deemed good enough?

I'd be interested if you have seen relevant discussions about that topic.

Comment: Programmers don't carelessly write the version number `foobar@^1.2.3`; it's the default config.

Comment: SO is a Q&A platform for fact based answers and not one for topic discussion. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question and SO may not be the right place for an open discussion about the benefits of package-lock.json.

There are several benefits as you have mentioned. (e.g.: Tighter package version control.) Details on the benefits can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-lock-json).

I will say that one of the main benefits of package-lock is that it includes all of the dependencies down the entire stack. This helps with optimization of the package tree for eliminating redundancies while ensuring reproducible and exact package tree versions for deployment. From the docs:

> As of npm v7, lockfiles include enough information to gain a complete
> picture of the package tree, reducing the need to read package.json
> files, and allowing for significant performance improvements.